# Element whose visibility is changed by javascript is not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjvz9rzu/4/)

I have the following CSS/Javascript code you can find in the fiddle, I'm trying to get an element to popup once it's clicked (to be used as a tooltip).

This part is working, however I'm trying to have another action once that popup is clicked once again. However, the pop up is absolutely not clickable (clicking on the popup just clicks the button under it. Does not actually click the popup itself).

I've tried to set a high `z-index` for the popup element in CSS, I've tried to set a `pointer-event: none` to the button, and I tried setting a `pointer-event: all` to the popup but also to no avail. All other questions regarding this topic asked on stackoverflow actually have the opposite problem. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Note: expected result is for javascript to log `test2` instead of `test1` just in case you did not understand what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: Well, seeing as the popup is **inside** the button, that's generally what happens, when you click a child of a button, you're clicking the button

Comment: `stopPropagation()` will solve it -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xjvz9rzu/5/, but you really should move the popup outside the button

Comment: @adeneo This is not really true because if you click the button so that the pop up would show up and then you click the pop up, it doesn't log "test1" to the console. (However it does so the first time you actually press the button to bring out the pop up)

Comment: @adeneo Pop up is sadly still not clickable in the fiddle you linked.

Comment: Adeneo's fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: @nnnnnn Weird. It's console logging "test2" for you after clicking the pop up?

Comment: Yes. Also your comment about the original version not logging "test1" when clicking the popup is incorrect. When I run your original version clicking the pop up logs both "test2" and "test1" to the console (in that order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is over-engineered. You can skim a lot down, I've created a quick example on how you can achieve this. Move the child element outside, but wrap the button and the child element in a container to structure our html.

Then, we can just add click event listeners to activate the pop-up and console log your 'test2' when you click on the child element.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("emoji-button");
var popup = document.getElementById("emoji-box");

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
});

popup.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("do other stuff");
});
```

```css
#emoji-container {
  position: relative;
}

#emoji-box {
  display: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #3A7300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#emoji-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

#emoji-box.active {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji-container">
  <button id="emoji-button">Emoji Button</button>
  <div id="emoji-box">Some text</div>
</div>

Other content...
```

Comment: Yes sorry about all the weird class/rule names. This is copied from a larger project and I had to scale it down. Your answer works perfectly. However may I know, what was exactly wrong with my approach?

Comment: *"Your version is over-engineered."* - In what sense? Perhaps the OP had more CSS stuff than needed, but your shorter version produces a popup that is a completely different shape, so it is *under*-engineered.

Comment: @AliS You're adding click to a parent element that contains the child element. Therefore, whenever you click the element inside the parent element, it will also activate the parent elements click event.

Comment: The problem is both you and @nnnnnnn are telling that the child element is being activated in my fiddle (but it isn't. At least not for my browser.) Could this be a browser issue? I'm running Firefox 45.2.0 on Linux)

Comment: @nnnnnn subjective when functionality is the main problem in this thread and not styling. But the example has been updated to reflect original styling. The fix in the above comments kept activating the button click animation and was very annoying so I found a solution that works. And no I was not on about styling but simply the fact that nesting elements to obtain a pseudo pop-up is over-engineering the goal.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback @nnnnnn and question answerer. Since this was the only answer (and it gave me an idea about how to fix it, thanks a lot!) I've chosen it as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: @AliS I've updated the example with your pop-up styling. :) Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

BUTTONS are actually not HTML to DOM Elements, they are in fact - and before anything else - HTML to Browser Automation CONTROLS.

You cannot click inside a button content! (It doesn't matter if it contains HTML or not ).

That's what went wrong with your code. No User Interaction with the content within the Browser Control is possible.